# how to logout from laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to log out after register. how do I do that?

This is my register controller:

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user =  User::create([
      'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'secondname' => $data['secondname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'mobileno' => $data['mobileno'],
        'type' => $data['type'],
    ]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

    return $user;

    return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the url :-

`protected $redirectTo = '/where/you/want/to/redirect';`

after registration in `app/Http/Controller/Auth/RegisterController.php`

and for logout:-

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

Comment: Redirection or logout??

Answer (score 0):

Add this two line in your controller and check

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: it did not worked. it redirect to login page when i click register page :(

Comment: try this code " use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

    return redirect('/wherever/you/want');
}   "

Comment: please try after php artisan make:auth